# hi, i am trying to retrieve data (an image particularly) from Firebase Database to android but not success

Tags: android, firebase

I want to retrieve the image of the connected user like on play stores app in drawer menu but not a success and I don't know how to proceed. I have succeeded to show the user's name and email but not the image.

Comment: Hi sidi. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . There is no way to understand your question and problem

Comment: Thanks for correction, I appreciate the effort I'll pay attention

Comment: Hi sidi, paste some of your code, this part which you try to retrieve the image with. This will help us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Imagining you have url of the images stored in firebase server you can use GLIDE library [(library link)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to download and display the images from any server not only firebase

If you don't have the image stored in database then you should first store it and then retrieve it from url. you can learn how to do it from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Comment: i hava an image, in fact when i'm going to sign in the new user i insert in the same time user's image, it work perfectly, but when i'm come back to log in with this user that i just registered just the name and email are retrieved but i'm gonna  try your solution thanks very much

Comment: it's working thanks, but how to do it so that it gets the url of the connected user..?

Comment: am not sure what you are asking, could you please clarify or post your code thats not working